# Prevent Company Name From Translating

Tags: php, localization

How do you prevent WordPress from localizing a company name when using the localization functions?

In the following snippet will "Company Name" be translated?

```
<?php printf(__('Here is some text about %s', 'my_theme'), 'Company Name'); ?>
```

Is it best practice to not translate a company name and the name of individuals?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the company name will not be translated. However, you should at least make it possible to write the name in the native alphabet. Latin letters look really odd in some other alphabets.

There is also a legal issue: in some countries it is not allowed to use capital letters for anything but some reserved words, in some cases this applies to capital letters in words only. You put your users at risk if you enforce capital letters. That’s one of the many problems with the “capital P” filter in WordPress. :/

Comment: I appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is the same as:

```
$str = __('Here is some text about %s', 'my_theme');
printf($str, 'Company Name');
```

The translation occurs first, then your Company name is swapped in.

Is it best practice? Does the company translate its name in other media? In some circumstance, probably so. You should probably allow it to be translated.